# Deleting cells in tables, html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose that I have a 5by5 table in HTML and I want to be able to remove cells with a function so that not only will the data inside the cell be invisible, but the space taken up by the cell will also no longer be visible: For instance a function: (assume 'CellId' is the Id of a table cell i.e. a table data tag)

```
  function DeleteCell(CellId) {
document.getElementById("CellId").style.display = "none";
}
```

This code for me is simply removing the contents of the cell, but the space it is taking up is not removed. Any help much appreciated.

Edit: I do not want to get rid of the cell in question with DeleteCell

Comment: This is not really how tables are suppose to work

Comment: So what is your expected result? Do you want to remove the entire `<td>`...`</td>`?

Comment: @larz I want the space previously taken up by the cell to be gone.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var removeTheCell = function(){
  var cell = document.getElementById("removeMe")
  cell.style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Column 1
  </th>
  <th>
    Column 2
    </th>
  <th>
    Column 3
    </th>
    </tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    1
    </td>
  <td>
    Apples
    </td>
  <td>
    Red
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    2
    </td>
  <td id="removeMe">
    Pineapple
    </td>
  <td>
    Yellow
    </td>
  </table>
<button onclick="removeTheCell()">Remove Pineapple</button>
```

So maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but in this code, the space taken up by the cell is removed and this doesn't seem any different from the code you have posted.  Let me know what I am missing or if this help clarify thing.